# In Laravel Blade, how to replace URL with route in search results of "sidebar-search" AdminLte v.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, adminlte

I am using Laravel 8 with blade template and AdminLte v3. I added "sidebar-search" to the menu to search for menus and it worked. i read from adminLte Sidebar docs [here](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1/javascript/sidebar-search.html) `https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1/javascript/sidebar-search.html`

but the problem is:
***In the search results, the URL displayed is wrong, so when clicked, it displays 404 not found.***

**Here is the code on Blade:**

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group" data-widget="sidebar-search">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar bg-white" type="search"
            placeholder="Cari menu" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-sidebar bg-white">
                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw text-primary"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the code for the menu I use:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route('notifikasi.index') }}"
        class="nav-link <?= request()->routeIs('notifikasi.*') ? 'active text-primary' : '' ?>">
        <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
        <p>
            Notifikasi
        </p>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route('logs') }}" class="nav-link <?= request()->routeIs('logs*') ? 'active text-primary' : '' ?>">
        <i class="nav-icon far fa-circle"></i>
        <p>
            Aktivitas
        </p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here are the search results:

[image]

**Here is the generated URL Link Result:**

```
http://abcx.com/http%3A//abcx.com/posting
```

**URL Result I want :**

```
http://abcx.com/posting
```

How do I correct the URL of the search results?
I tried to change adminlte.js, but it doesn't work

Comment: `laravel` _and_ `codeigniter`, interesting. How is `jquery` related? How do you create those links?

Comment: I use route name in my menus : 
{{ route('notifikasi.index') }}

i used AdminLte3 without jquery added for that case.

Comment: @Alie How you are appending url in search suggestions on searching? The code where you're building the suggestion list, is concatenating your current URL & destination route. Plz show us your code for suggestion list then we can help you.

Comment: its handle by **adminlte.min.js**
I tried from this [adminlte.min.js](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1/javascript/sidebar-search.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Finally Solved!
It turns out it's very simple, no need to add jquery or javascript, just change the route name script."

From:

```
<a href="{{ route('statistik.database') }}" class="nav-link">
<p>Menu 1</p>
</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="{{ route('statistik.database', [], false) }}" class="nav-link">
<p>Menu 1</p>
</a>
```